# how to make VPN available to wi-fi network?

Tags: networking, vpn

We work extensively via VPN. Everybody needs to connect on their own, which is very [tedious](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/categories/VPN/).

I am thinking that there needs to be a router (box or linux) that I can connect to VPN from, and then everybody joins its wi-fi, is able to connect to our servers made available by VPN.

Have you done this before ?

Comment: Is there a possibility of switching off PPTP vpn?

Comment: Why are you required to use a VPN?  If someone is requiring each client to connect to a VPN for security reasons, then aren't you basically wrecking the security by allowing people to use it via wifi?

Comment: Anyway, yes setting up a linux device to connect to a VPN, and then share out the connection should be possible, if you can connect to the VPN under linux.  If you do this, then you would probably have to setup NAT on the linux device, and some network protocols don't work well over NAT.  If the services you need don't work over NAT, then you will have a lot of difficulty.

Comment: @zypher yes. we can connect via ssl.

Comment: @zoredache vpn should be enabled to our people at the office, its not a public wifi, so no problems with security.

Answer (score 1):

We are doing this at the moment, we have a router to router VPN tunnel that's open permanently. Anyone on the local network can see/interact with servers at the other end.

This Microsoft document may help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728081(WS.10).aspx

FYI: We are using Draytek Vigor routers.

If you can't install a router at the other end then perhaps another option would be to configure the VPN on one workstation and then share it for everyone to connect through it. At least then you would only need to configure it once.